# bash script syntax error: arithmetic expression required

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to do the following write a script that contain less than or greater than but it gave me the following error message: `syntax error: arithmetic expression required` please advise code example below:

```
  x=1
     for ($x -lt 21) -- I tried the following expressions: ($x <21), ("$x"<21), ("$x" -lt 21)
        do
        if ($x!=7 or $x!=15);
        then
        echo $x
        fi
x++
        done
```

error message I am receiving:

```
./test1.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `-lt'
./test1.sh: line 2: ` for ($x -lt 21)'
```

Comment: That's not the syntax for a bash/sh for loop. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet?highlight=%28for%29%7C%28loop%29#Loops and http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs

Comment: Is that `for` supposed to be an `if` or a `while`? You've shown us code that's clearly incorrect, but you haven't given us enough information to guess what the corresponding correct code would look like.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i x=1

while [ $x -lt 21 ]; do 
    [ $x -ne 7 -a $x -ne 15 ] && printf  "%s\n" $x
    ((x++))
done
```

**Output**

```
$ bash thescript.sh
1
2
3
4
5
6
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
16
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: Did you try that? I got `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `$x'`

Comment: Jesus you guys jump on the downvote bandwagon quickly. Sorry for the mistype. I'll be sure and return the favor...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I downvoted because your answer was incorrect. I've withdrawn my downvote now that your answer is correct. I advise being less sensitive.

Comment: Obviously there was a `for/while` brainfart. What makes this place so unpalatable at times is the "oh we caught a mistake -- nail him" attitude that is so pervasive on this list. I'm glad the list was changed to make people put skin in the game for a downvote, but in most instances, a simple courteous comment will do.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the OP posted as a comment in another answer that he's trying to learn about `for` loops.  So while at first glance this may seem like a "for/while brainfart" it seems that neither of our answers may actually be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I gave up trying to glean the exact request here. If it is a `for` loop needed, then a `c-style` loop or a `for i in $(seq 1 21) ...` Just another example where **no good deed goes unpunished...** `:p`

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you express a condition.  `man test` for details.

You probably want something more like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=1
while [ $x -lt 21 ]; do
    if [ $x -ne 7 ] || [ $x -ne 15 ]; then
        echo $x
    fi
    # don't forget to set x to something else, or the loop will never finish.
done
```

I've used `while` instead of `for` because .. `for` steps through a set of values, whereas `while` checks the result of a test.

Note that this STILL isn't correct, because your "or" condition is .. wonky.  No matter what `$x` is, the condition will evaluate true, because in ALL case the variable is either "not 7" or it's "not 15".

But this is most likely an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna, the question remains .. what are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I am learning skip in bash script with a loop using for statement

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, of course it is, you haven't read the comment, or the text below.  The code I provided simply corrected the *format*.  The OP's original post didn't include any logic to change the value of `$x`, and I wasn't about to make assumptions about his requirements.